# Gradient fields with holes and the fundamental theorem of line integrals

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm learning vector calculus for the GRE, so this is my first time encountering these concepts. To my knowledge, a gradient field $\mathbf{F}(x,y) : D\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is one where there exists a scalar function $f(x,y) : D\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$ \mathbf{F}=\nabla f $$
Here, I'm not specifying $D$ to be simply-connected, or even open. I believe this is a valid definition for any subset $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

The fundamental theorem for line integral states that if $\mathbf{F}$ is a gradient field, i.e. $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ for some $f$, then along any path $C$ given by the parameterization $\mathbf{r}(t)$ for $a\leq t \leq b$
$$ \int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}= f(\mathbf{r}(b))- f(\mathbf{r}(a)) $$

*This might be a dumb question, but what if the domain has holes?*

For example, take the scalar function $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$ then the corresponding gradient field is $\mathbf{F}(x,y) = \left( \frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \frac{x(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \right)$.

I tried to take the line integral over the upper half circle, and the lower half circle, and it turns out they are both zero. *Could I have applied the fundamental theorem of line integrals to this vector field $\mathbf{F}$?*

Comment: I don't believe so. Can you look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could have use the theorem. If you take a look at the short proof of the theorem,

\begin{align*}
\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r} &= \int_a^b \mathbf{F} (\mathbf{r} (t)) \mathbf{r}'(t) dt\\
&= \int_a^b\nabla f (\mathbf{r} (t)) \mathbf{r}'(t) dt \\
&= \int_a^b \frac{d}{dt} (f\circ \mathbf{r})(t) dt\\
&= (f\circ \mathbf{r})(b)-(f\circ \mathbf{r})(a).
\end{align*}

We used only chain rule and the standard fundamental theorem of calculus. No assumptions about the domain $D$ (besides that the curve $C$ lies inside $D$).

Comment: I don't believe this is true, because $\mathbf{F}$ is not actually a gradient vector field over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you look at my answer and see if you agree?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you cannot apply FTLI if the gradient field has holes. I believe the (almost) gradient field
$$\vec{F} (x, y) = \left(\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right)$$
which is (almost) the gradient of $f = \arctan(y/x)$ (except that $f$ is not defined at $(0, 0)$). It has the property that
$$\int_C \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = 2 \pi$$
for any closed curve $C$ which surrounds the origin. What you can do for such problematic vector fields, however, is to notice that $\vec{F}$ is a gradient field *away* from its discontinuities, so you can always evaluate the above integral by deforming $C$ into any nice closed loop you like (and here, a particularly nice one is the unit circle). In other words,
$$\int_C \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = \int_{C'} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}$$
for any $C'$ also containing the origin (which is the only problematic point) and preserving orientation. The reason that such a deformation is possible is due to Stokes' Theorem, which notes that
$$\int_{\partial A} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = \iint_{A} (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}) \cdot \vec{dA}$$
for any $A$, as long as the function is $\mathcal{C}^2$ over $A$. Choosing $A$ to be $C \setminus C'$, we can see that
$$\int_{\partial A} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = \int_C \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} - \int_{C'} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = \iint_{A} (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}) \cdot \vec{dA} = 0$$

Comment: Note that your function f is not defined when $x=0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar You’re right. For the function that OP offers though, the domain is not a simply connected region, so we still cannot conclude it is a gradient field. I’ll see if I can find an exception where the only discontinuity is a hole.